# Unable to remove label field from the registration form

Tags: forms

I am unable to remove the label from a form element of the registration form.

I have:

- Enabled the kint module for debugging
- Implemented `hook_form_alter()` and tried to change the form variables

  ```
  function drupalfresh_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    kint($form);
    $form['field_company_name']['#attributes']['widget'][0]['#title'] = t('');
  }
  ```

This doesn't change the form.

This is how the form element appears.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I cant do it in the css but i dont want to go by the css way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try the code below:

```
$form['field_company_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']='';
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the can be changed using this code:

`$form['field_company_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = $this->t('WHATEVER');`

Comment: In Drupal 8 this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Sorry the answer was edited

Comment: $this in here gives a fatal error though its close to what i was looking . Solved. Thanks